# Netperf 2.7.0 installation not working using the enable-demo option

Tags: linux, networking, benchmarking, ubuntu-18.04, throughput

I'm trying to install netperf 2.7.0 in a VM running Ubuntu 18.04. Since the version installed using apt-get is 2.6.0, I had to download the TAR file from https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/releases and go thru the install/compilation process

The installation is very straightforward if compiled with no parameters: ./configure

In that case the installation is successfull.

However, I'm installing netperf to run with flent for bandwidth benchmarking, so netperf needs to be compiled with the --enable-demo option.

So, when I type ./configure --enable-demo,  all seems to be ok

$make also looks fine but at the end shows some errors:

> Makefile:304: recipe for target 'netperf' failed
>   make[3]: *** [netperf] Error 1
>   make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
>   Makefile:352: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
>   make[2]:**  [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
>   Makefile:277: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
>   make[1]:  **[all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0'
>   Makefile:215: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make:**  [all] Error 2
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:304: recipe for target 'netperf' failed
>   make[3]:  **[netperf] Error 1
>   make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
>   Makefile:352: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
>   make[2]:**  [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
>   Makefile:277: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
>   make[1]:  **[all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0'
>   Makefile:215: recipe for target 'all' failed
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Finally $make install shows the following output:

> Making install in src
>   make[1]: Entering directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
>   Making install in missing
>   make[2]: Entering directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing'
>   Making install in m4
>   make[3]: Entering directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing/m4'
>   make[4]: Entering directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing/m4'
>   make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
>   make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
>   make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing/m4'
>   make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing/m4'
>   make[3]: Entering directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing'
>   make[4]: Entering directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing'
>   make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
>   make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
>   make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing'
>   make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing'
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src/missing'
>   make[2]: Entering directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
>   gcc     -o netperf netperf.o netlib.o netsh.o nettest_bsd.o nettest_dlpi.o nettest_unix.o nettest_xti.o nettest_sctp.o nettest_sdp.o nettest_omni.o net_uuid.o dscp.o netcpu_procstat.o  -lm
>   netlib.o: In function `demo_interval_final':
>   netlib.c:(.text+0x43db): undefined reference to`demo_interval_display'
>   netlib.o: In function `demo_stream_interval':
>   netlib.c:(.text+0x4401): undefined reference to`demo_interval_tick'
>   netlib.o: In function `demo_rr_interval':
>   netlib.c:(.text+0x4477): undefined reference to`demo_interval_tick'
>   nettest_omni.o: In function `send_omni_inner':
>   nettest_omni.c:(.text+0x99ec): undefined reference to`demo_interval_tick'
>   nettest_omni.c:(.text+0x9a03): undefined reference to `demo_interval_tick'
>   nettest_omni.c:(.text+0x9a2c): undefined reference to`demo_interval_tick'
>   nettest_omni.o:nettest_omni.c:(.text+0x9a3b): more undefined references to `demo_interval_tick' follow
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:304: recipe for target 'netperf' failed
>   make[2]: *** [netperf] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
>   Makefile:352: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
>   make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/administrator/Downloads/netperf-netperf-2.7.0/src'
>   Makefile:277: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
>   make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

When I verify if netperf was installed I get no answer:

> bash: /usr/local/bin/netperf: No such file or directory

So, the files netperf and netderver are missing after the installation.

To sum up, the installation fails when the "enable-demo" is used during compilation.

Am I missing something? I'd appreciate any clue on this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> netlib.c:(.text+0x4401): undefined reference to demo_interval_tick'
>
> nettest_omni.c:(.text+0x99ec): undefined reference
>   to demo_interval_tick'

The files are 5 years old: `sudo apt install g++-4.8`

```
cd netperf-netperf-2.7.0/
export CC=gcc-4.8 CXX=g++-4.8 && ./configure --enable-demo
make
sudo make install    // No errors
```